# Using a remote file as input in Talend

Tags: talend

My problem is that I want to read an excel file from a remote server in my talend job. I am using tFileFetch but the issue is that while using tFileFetch it's copying the file in the local disk but I don't want to copy the file in local disk I want to perform an operation on a file and put it on my database. My problem is that the component tFileInputExcel seems to accept only local files and don't recognize my HTTP string: http://yadav.in/excel/bs.xlsx.
Is there a particular syntax? or did I forget to do something? a component that will download the file to feed the tFileInputExcel.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure `tFileFetch` to cache the file in memory, instead of saving it to disk. Then use an input stream to read it with `tFileInputExcel`; like so:

[image]

- Check the option, "Use cache to save the resource" on `tFileFetch`
- Use the global variable `tFileFetch_1_INPUT_STREAM`, of type `java.io.InputStream` as a the stream in `tFileInputExcel`